# How to display related items in datatable?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I currently display all restaurants in a datatable, but restaurants can also have branches/franchises, so I am trying to display these as well in the same table.

At the moment I display them as follows:

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
    $restaurant = Restaurant::query()->with('user');

    return Datatables::of($restaurant)
        ->editColumn('name', function ($restaurant) {
            return $restaurant->name;
        })
        ->editColumn('user.name', function ($restaurant) { // Owner
            return $restaurant->user->name;
        })
        ->editColumn('total_orders', function ($restaurant) {
            return $restaurant->total_orders;
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

My relationship is that Restaurant `hasMany(Branch::class);` and Branch `belongsTo(Restaurant::class);`

I fail to think of a solution that allows me to display all the branches (`$restaurant->branches->get()`) inside the same restaurant datatable.

Any help and hints would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can do this with the query builder and then do multiple joins I prefer to do it like this.

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::select('restaurant.name as name, user.name as owner,         
     restaurant.total_orders as total_orders, branches.*')
->with('user', 'branches');
```